# threshold_local returns a different result than threshold_adaptive in scikit-image

Tags: python, image-processing, scikit-image, threshold

I'm reproducing this [example](http://scikit-image.org/docs/0.12.x/auto_examples/segmentation/plot_threshold_adaptive.html) from the documentation:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from skimage import data
from skimage.filters import threshold_otsu, threshold_adaptive


image = data.page()

global_thresh = threshold_otsu(image)
binary_global = image > global_thresh

block_size = 35
binary_adaptive = threshold_adaptive(image, block_size, offset=10)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3, figsize=(7, 8))
ax0, ax1, ax2 = axes
plt.gray()

ax0.imshow(image)
ax0.set_title('Image')

ax1.imshow(binary_global)
ax1.set_title('Global thresholding')

ax2.imshow(binary_adaptive)
ax2.set_title('Adaptive thresholding')

for ax in axes:
    ax.axis('off')

plt.show()
```

There threshold_adaptive, but it raises a warning:

[image]

"UserWarning: The return value of `threshold_local` is a threshold image, while `threshold_adaptive` returned the *thresholded* image"

But when I use threshold_adaptive the result is different:

[image]

Comment: @CrisLuengo My question is how can I get the same result in both methods since it is supposed to be the same function. I Updated the code

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If we look at the [documentation for `threshold_adaptive`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.filters.html#skimage.filters.threshold_adaptive), we see it has been deprecated in favor of a new function `threshold_local`. Unfortunately, that one doesn't seem to be documented.

We can still look at [older documentation](http://scikit-image.org/docs/0.12.x/api/skimage.filters.html#threshold-adaptive) to find out what `threshold_adaptive` does: it applies an adaptive threshold, yielding a binary output image.

The undocumented `threshold_local`, in contrast, doesn't return a binary image, as you found out. [Here is an example](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/xx_applications/plot_thresholding.html) for how to use it:

```
block_size = 35
adaptive_thresh = threshold_local(image, block_size, offset=10)
binary_adaptive = image > adaptive_thresh
```

What is happening?

The function computes, for each pixel, a threshold. But instead of directly applying that threshold, it returns an image containing all these thresholds. Comparing the original image with the threshold image is the way to apply the threshold, yielding a binary image.